# $\sup\{2^{-n}(2n-1), n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have that $$\{2^{-n}(2n-1), n\in\mathbb{N}\}=\left\{-1, \frac12, \frac34, \frac58,\ldots\right\}$$

i proved that from $n=2$ the sequence $(2^{-n}(2n-1))$ is decreasing then can i deduce that $\sup\{2^{-n}(2n-1), n\in\mathbb{N}\}=\frac34$

and the infinimum is $-1$ ?

Thank you

Comment: Seems right to me.

Comment: The infimum is, in fact, a minimum in this case.

Comment: the suprimum is also a maximum right ?

Comment: @PolineSandra yes that's correct, since they belong to the set.